# Shortening a switch case method for JLabels

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a method that takes in a Briefcase, and the user's selected briefcase number which holds a value. For example .getValue1() returns a JLabel. What can I do to shorten this switch case so I am not repeating code?

```
public void removeValueDisplay(Briefcase briefcase, int caseNum) {

    switch (Model.briefcases[caseNum - 1].getValue()) 
    {
        case 1:
            view.getValue1().setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            view.getValue2().setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case 5:
            view.getValue5().setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case 10:
            view.getValue10().setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case 25:
            view.getValue25().setEnabled(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

There are 26 cases in total, which I haven't included in this code

Comment: How about a method `getValue(int)` over `getValue1()` to `getValue26()`. That sounds awfully repetitive.

Comment: Put your ``JLabel``s into a ``List`` or ``JLabel[]`` so you can access them with a numerical index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of JLabel in your Briefcase class to store your labels. Then an accessor for all at once:

```
public JLabel[] getValues();
```

Or to retrieve only the one you want:

```
public JLabel getValue(int number);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help everyone. This how I've shortened my code:

```
public void removeValueDisplay(int caseNum) {

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.briefcases.length; ++i) {
       if(Model.briefcases[caseNum - 1].getValue() == Model.values[i]) {
           view.getValueLabels()[i].setEnabled(false);
       }
    }
```